# How to print to 3 different printers from 3 different buttons with JS?

Tags: javascript, php, printing

well,  I have this restaurant POS system which has to print three receipts when the order is made one should go to the kitchen as KOT,other to the bar and the last one to the reception for making the bills.I am thinking of making three buttons which will be assigned to three different printers.I researched a lot around but couldn't find a way to do this.It is even possible I used PHP and JS to make the application.

Is is possible for any othe programming language to do it?

Comment: `restaurant POS system` - what environment does it run in? a browser?

Comment: You won't be able to natively access the printers using JS or PHP - although PHP could probably issue a direct print via the system, using exec() or similar, but that would depend on what system you're on, and would involve some sort of command-line access to the different printers.

Comment: It run on browser..it a web application

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie i am currently on windows os and have windows 10.Is there any command line to do this?